# Actionscript 3.0 - Sort an array of instances by their properties?

Tags: arrays, class, sorting, actionscript, instances

I have an Array which has Class instances in it.
These class instances have several properties.
Let's say I want to sort this array by the name property of each instance.

```
public class Thing
{

    public var name:String;

    public function Thing(name:String)
    {
         this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And here is what the Array might look like:

```
var ar:Array = new Array(new Thing("Apple"), new Thing("Compass"), 
                         new Thing("Banana"), new Thing("Alligator"));
```

After sorting it and looping through it to trace each instance's name property, it should output like this:
Alligator, Apple, Banana, Compass

Answer (score 0):

You could sort by

ar.sortOn(property, options);

in your case the property would be "name" and option would ARRAY.ASCENDING

PS: I havent tried, but give it a go: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sortOn()

Answer (score 0):

`sortOn` should probably work, or you can pass it through your own custom sort function:

```
private function _sortArray( a:Thing, b:Thing ):int
{
    if ( a.name < b.name )
        return -1; // a goes before b
    else if ( a.name > b.name )
        return 1; // b goes before a
    return 0; // order doesn't matter
}
```

You can then call it via:

```
ar.sort( _sortArray );
```

Sort functions take two parameters of the type stored in the array (in your case, `Thing`), and return either <= `-1` if `a` should go before `b`, >= `1` if `b` should go before `a`, or `0` if the order doesn't matter (i.e. the names are the same). You can compare pretty much anything to get the sorting you want. E.g., to get a random sort:

```
private function _sortArray( a:Thing, b:Thing ):int
{
    if ( Math.random() < 0.5 )
        return -1;
    return 1;
}
```